# MVC 4 models not accept jquery datapicker date format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Entity framwork 6 , MVC 4 and jquery datepicker. When fill all the form data and press the submit button the **ModelState.IsValid** always return false value, because the jquery datepicker value not match with the model validation field.

**in .cshtml file**

```
-----
-----
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Annieversary, new { id = "anudate", @class = "form-control datetimepicker", @placeholder = "Annieversary Date" })
-----
-----
```

**c# Side**

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date required")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Annieversary { get; set; }
```

I tried below

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Annieversary,"{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { id = "anudate", @class = "form-control datetimepicker", @placeholder = "Annieversary" })
```

This is also not match with the model, always return null value. I know c# only accept the "MM/DD/YYYY" format but jquery datepicker return "DD/MM/YYYY" format. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130937/discussion-on-question-by-merbin-jo-mvc-4-models-not-accept-jquery-datapicker-da).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's simplify so it can work. Then you can add the attributes you feel you need.

**Model**
Notice that I am using the question mark to make the field nullable - as I understand you will need it:

```
public DateTime? Anniversary { get; set; }
```

**View**
Notice the `datepicker` class, which we will use to call the jQuery UI DatePicker component:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Anniversary, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

**JavaScript**
Notice that I am setting the `dateFormat` to the format you need. That helps but it's not enough just yet:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
});
</script>
```

**Web.Config**
Now, here is where the magic happens. You need to set the culture of your application in order to have the proper date format. I have it set to `pt-BR`, which gives the same date format you need:

```
<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR"/>
```

That should do it, but it's the most basic example.

The most important thing to remember is: **The date format should always match the culture you set in the web.config**.